# How to use the Chain Rule to find the magnitude of the derivative of a vector function?

Tags: calculus, vectors

I'm trying to find the magnitude of a vector $\dot{\vec{r}}(t)$ by two different methods, but get different results. 
Let $\vec{r}(t)=x(t)\hat{x}+y(t)\hat{y}$. The magnitude of this vector is:
$$ ||\vec{r}(t)|| = \sqrt{x(t)^2 + y(t)^2} $$
The time derivative of $\vec{r}(t)$ must then be
$$\dot{\vec{r}}(t) = \dot{x}(t)\hat{\dot{x}}+\dot{y}(t)\hat{\dot{y}}$$
Now, using the same formula for the magnitude as before yields:
$$||\dot{\vec{r}}(t)|| = \sqrt{\dot{x}(t)^2 + \dot{y}(t)^2}$$
But when I try to find the magnitude of $\dot{\vec{r}}(t)$ by differentiating $||\vec{r}(t)||$ with respect to time, the chain rule gives me:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}||\vec{r}|| &= \frac{\partial ||\vec{r}||}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial ||\vec{r}||}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}
\\
&= \frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\dot{x}+\frac{2y}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\dot{y}
\\
&= \dot{x}\frac{x}{||r||} + \dot{y}\frac{y}{||r||} \neq \sqrt{\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2}
\end{align}
$$
Where it is implicit that all the functions are evaluated in $t$. Have I made an algebraic mistake, or is it not possible to find $||\dot{\vec{r}}(t)||$ by differentiation? - and if so, why?

Comment: There is a miscalculation in the d/dt ||r|| calculation, but does not change the overall result that, as user Duncan Ramage points out, there is no symmetry between the norm of a vector function and the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one equation, you take the magnitude and then differentiate, and in the other you differentiate and then take the magnitude. I don't see any reason why these two operations would be equivalent.

For example, consider $f(x) = x^2$. Then, $f'(x) = 2x$, and $|f'(x)| = 2|x|$. Meanwhile, $|f(x)| = x^2$ and $|f(x)|' = 2x$. These two functions clearly differ on the negative real numbers.